Apple Login with Next_Auth : error=OAuthCallback
i'm trying to login with apple using next auth its authanticate user but redirect to /?error=OAuthCallback
this is the url= https://appleid.apple.com/auth/authorize?client_id=com.wheeleasy.org&scope=name%20email&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelop-sr3snxi-sq2r64cdk53qe.au.platformsh.site%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Fcallback%2Fapple&response_mode=form_post&code_challenge=lelepvmyqyryTiyWL6NthxspYae6t9XYB1PAj3e3c_E&code_challenge_method=S256
enter image description here
this is my code for genrating client secret and client secret genrated successfully
const { SignJWT } = require("jose");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const { createPrivateKey } = require("crypto");

// Constants for Apple API credentials
const teamId = process.env.TEAM_ID;
const clientId = process.env.CLIENT_ID;
const keyId = process.env.KEY_ID;
const expiresIn = 86400 * 180;
const privateKeyPath = path.join(__dirname, "AuthKey_CW5NRK3ZSN.p8");
const exp = Math.ceil(Date.now() / 1000) + expiresIn;
const expiresAt = Math.ceil(Date.now() / 1000) + expiresIn;
const expirationTime = exp ?? expiresAt;
// Read the private key from file
let privateKey;
try {
  privateKey = fs.readFileSync(privateKeyPath, "utf8");
  console.log("Private Key Read Successfully");
} catch (err) {
  console.error("Error reading private key:", err);
  process.exit(1);
}
// Create the JWT (client secret) using the jose library
(async () => {
  try {
    const jwt = await new SignJWT({})
      .setAudience("https://appleid.apple.com")
      .setIssuer(teamId)
      .setIssuedAt()
      .setExpirationTime(expirationTime)
      .setSubject(clientId)
      .setProtectedHeader({ alg: "ES256", kid: keyId, typ: "JWT" })
      .sign(createPrivateKey(privateKey));

    console.log("Client Secret:", jwt);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error generating JWT:", err);
  }
})();

import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import FacebookProvider from "next-auth/providers/facebook";
import AppleProvider from "next-auth/providers/apple";

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    FacebookProvider({
      clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    AppleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.APPLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.APPLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    session: async ({ session, token }) => {
      if (session?.user) {
        session.user.id = token.uid;
      }
      return session;
    },
    jwt: async ({ user, token }) => {
      if (user) {
        token.uid = user.id;
      }
      return token;
    },
  },
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
});

i have all the info like team_id , key_id, AuthKey_CW5NRK3ZSN.p8 file to genrate client secret
im trying to login with apple but its ridercting me to error page /?error=OAuthCallback
i want integrate apple login successfully

I think you should use "redirect=false" in the signIn logic then you can console log res.error to understand the error you are facing.
Redirect = false will prevent your app from redirecting to default next.js error page when you run in to a signin error.

nothing will be consoled. It goes  to the Apple site when we provide Apple ID and password then it redirects to our site, and then it goes to "https://develop-sr3snxi-sq2r64cdk53qe.au.platformsh.site/api/auth/signin?error=OAuthCallback"
